# Subscribing to answers - No need to send me an e-mail if there's an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, subscription

I normally visit SO every day, but I rarely go to SF and SU, except to ask a question. In those two, I always get subscribed by e-mail, just in case i forget to get back and check for answers.

Now, in many cases, I get the answer in the same day and mark it as accepted. In those cases, I don't really need the e-mail to notify me the day after (and it's actually kind of confusing), so I propose to disable it for questions with accepted answers.

The reasoning here being "if I mark an answer as accepted, I've moved on, i'm no longer looking for another answer"

Just my 2 cents, may this is not that good an idea for everyone, not sure.

Comment: Just uncheck the "Notify [your e-mail here] daily of any new answers" option at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I wouldn't like this. I want to keep being notified of alternatives even after I've accepted one, just in case something even better comes along. I agree with @ChrisF, if you don't want the notifications any more you can disable the option when it's appropriate for you.